# Make Jackson ObjectMapper Serializable

Tags: serialization, wicket, jackson

I'm trying to use Jackson's ObjectMapper in Wicket. It's working in general, but throwing a serialization exception: `[class=org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper] <----- field that is not serializable`

I'm setting up the field with `private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();`.

Trying `private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setSerializerProvider(new StdSerializerProvider());` leads to the same result. I assume I'm missing the right (combination of) configurations?! Any pointers to the right combination would be highly appreciated.

The full stack trace:

```
*ERROR:Error serializing object class ....web.backend.overview.OverviewPage [object=[Page class = ....web.backend.overview.OverviewPage, id = 1, render count = 1]]
org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker$WicketNotSerializableException: Unable to serialize class: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
Field hierarchy is:
  1 [class=....web.backend.overview.OverviewPage, path=1]
    private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=[Ljava.lang.Object;]
      private org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine ....web.BasePanel.velocityEngine[5] [class=....web.backend.overview.MailBoxQuickOverViewPanel, path=1:mailboxQuickOverviewPanel]
        private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=[Ljava.lang.Object;]
          private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children[0] [class=....web.backend.overview.ChartPanel, path=1:mailboxQuickOverviewPanel:chartPanel]
            private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=com.comsysto.insight.component.HighchartsPanel, path=1:mailboxQuickOverviewPanel:chartPanel:chart]
              private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=[Ljava.lang.Object;]
                private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children[1] [class=org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label, path=1:mailboxQuickOverviewPanel:chartPanel:chart:script]
                  java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.Component.data [class=com.comsysto.insight.component.HighchartsPanel$1]
                    final com.comsysto.insight.model.Highchart com.comsysto.insight.component.HighchartsPanel$1.val$highcharts [class=com.comsysto.insight.model.Highchart]
                      private org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper com.comsysto.insight.model.Highchart.mapper [class=org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper] <----- field that is not serializable
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:386) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.checkFields(SerializableChecker.java:646) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:569) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.checkFields(SerializableChecker.java:646) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:569) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.checkFields(SerializableChecker.java:646) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:569) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:431) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.checkFields(SerializableChecker.java:646) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:569) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.checkFields(SerializableChecker.java:646) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:569) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:431) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.checkFields(SerializableChecker.java:646) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:569) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:431) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.checkFields(SerializableChecker.java:646) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.internalCheck(SerializableChecker.java:569) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.check(SerializableChecker.java:365) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.SerializableChecker.writeObjectOverride(SerializableChecker.java:715) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer$CheckerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JavaSerializer.java:258) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer.serialize(JavaSerializer.java:77) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DefaultPageStore.serializePage(DefaultPageStore.java:368) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DefaultPageStore.storePage(DefaultPageStore.java:146) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageStoreManager$PersistentRequestAdapter.storeTouchedPages(PageStoreManager.java:383) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.RequestAdapter.commitRequest(RequestAdapter.java:171) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.AbstractPageManager.commitRequest(AbstractPageManager.java:94) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageManagerDecorator.commitRequest(PageManagerDecorator.java:68) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer$2.commitRequest(PageAccessSynchronizer.java:281) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.Application$2.onDetach(Application.java:1598) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$3.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:99) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$3.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:97) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection$1.notify(ListenerCollection.java:119) [wicket-util-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.reversedNotify(ListenerCollection.java:143) [wicket-util-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.reversedNotifyIgnoringExceptions(ListenerCollection.java:113) [wicket-util-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection.onDetach(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:95) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.onDetach(RequestCycle.java:600) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.detach(RequestCycle.java:539) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:287) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:162) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:218) [wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359) [shiro-web-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:275) [shiro-web-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:344) [shiro-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:272) [shiro-web-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81) [shiro-web-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [na:1.6.0_29]
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer$CheckerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JavaSerializer.java:250) ~[wicket-core-1.5.4.jar:1.5.4]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This seems like you're trying to serialize `ObjectMapper` itself. Why would you do that?

Comment: In my understanding, the ``mapper`` needs to be serializable, but isn't. So I'm trying to make it serializable. Or is this even the wrong approach?

Comment: `ObjectMapper` is used for serializing other objects. Why do you think you need to serialize it here?

Comment: Ok, I've added the full stack trace above. I assume I need to serialize it, because of ``Unable to serialize class: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper``. If this isn't the case - what would I need to serialize?

Comment: You have a class. That class has a field which is an `ObjectMapper`. `ObjectMapper` **is not meant to be Serialized**, it's meant for **serializing other objects**. Why are you trying to serialize the class which contains the `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: Wicket requires any field to be serializable - otherwise you'll run into the error message above. I've now worked around this by making ``mapper`` a local variable, where this isn't required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ObjectMapper` should not be serialized. It is not Serializable, and for good reason.

So you have some other issue related to your usage: as others have pointed out, there is no reason that serializability or lack thereof of `ObjectMapper` should cause problems.
Most likely you are accidentally having dependencies to Mapper or such: remove those dependencies. Mappers are typically either accessed as static singletons (which is fine), or injected using something like Guice or Spring IoC.

Based on the original question, you probably should just create a static instance of `ObjectMapper` -- it is very important NOT to create new instance for each request, but to reuse instance(s).

**EDIT** (2013/10): as pointed out by @Jason, `ObjectMapper`, this is no longer true. Turns out there is one potential reason, when used on some platforms -- for example, on Android, ability to "freeze" a mapper can be performance win. I would not recommend it as a default strategy, but is an option at least.

Comment: That's because it's expensive to create new instances? I've also tried final static, but that didn't help with the serialization exception. My current solution is https://github.com/xeraa/Ubercharts/blob/master/ubercharts-lib/src/main/java/com/comsysto/insight/model/Highchart.java#L82 - or is that totally wrong?

Comment: Creation is not expensive, but you will incur heavy first-use cost for everything: mapper is the thing that caches all necessary pieces. So it will be 10x - 100x slower than if you reuse instance.

Comment: Static member should work (you already have static Logger). You can also try adding keyword 'transient', since transient entries are not serialized.

Comment: Stupid me - ``private static final transient`` it is. Thanks!

Comment: Actually as of 2.1 ObjectMapper IS serializable